# How to call python function every time in Odoo 10

Tags: javascript, odoo-10

I have a button on `purchase.order` which does something I want to run the function of the button automatically when Purchase order is created form Sale Order which is done via Procurement.

I think this is also possible through javascript when the screen loads(do not know much js).

```
class Purchase_Order(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'purchase.order'

    @api.multi
    def _unlink_imprint_charges(self):
        self.env['purchase.order.line'].search(['&', ('order_id', '=', self.ids), ('is_charge', '=', True)]).unlink()

    @api.multi
    def charge_set_po(self):
        self._unlink_imprint_charges()
        for obj in self.order_line:
            obj.env['purchase.order.line']._add_imprint_location(obj, self)
```

I want to call the `charge_set_po` function when urser clicks on the PO or when Procurement is done.

Answer (score 0):

You create a compute field for this purpose.

```
@api.one
def _foo(self):
   print 'Foo'

action_compute = fields.Char(compute='_foo')
```

This function will work whenever you click a purchase order in tree view.